# Android PHP POST Login

Tags: java, android

I've tried finding the answers in other posts and avoid posting a duplicate; however, many were using deprecated methods. I am trying to create a login activity which will POST user details to php and receive a jsonEncoded status "Authorized" or "Incorrect User Details" response; I've tested the PHP and it works. When I click on the Login Button it will do this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnLogin:

            String username = Username.getText().toString();
            String password = Password.getText().toString();

            User user = new User(username, password);

            authenticate(user);

            userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);
            userLocalStore.storeUserData(user);

            break;
    }
}
```

It contains the User function, which makes it easier for me to pass information.

```
String username, password;

public User (String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}
```

Once the User is constructed, Login will call on the authenticate function:

```
private void authenticate(User user) {

    ServerRequests serverRequests = new ServerRequests(this);
    serverRequests.fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, returnedUser);{

        if (returnedUser == null){
            showErrorMessage();
        } else {
            logUserIn();
        }
    };
}
```

Once the user is authenticated it will log the user in and start a new activity:

```
private void logUserIn() {
    userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Map.class));
}
```

The issue I'm having, is that it doesn't seem to make the call to the php, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong; I've tried piecing together what others have done, but it's not working. I'd appreciate any help.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

public class ServerRequests {

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public ServerRequests(Context context) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Authenticating...");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    }

    public void fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, String returnedUser) {
        progressDialog.show();
        new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, returnedUser).execute();
    }

    public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        User user;
        String returnedUser;


        public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, String returnedUser) {
            this.user = user;
            this.returnedUser = returnedUser;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {

                url = new URL("www.mysite.com/test.php");

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                String param = "username="+user.username+"&password="+user.password;
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
                conn.connect();

                OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                out.write(param);

               //No code to receive response yet, want to get the POST working first. 

            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            return returnedUser;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to remove  `catch(Exception e)` block because at the moment it overrides all the exception blocks and does nothing. Then you need to debug your code in those blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this..

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
String param = "username="+user.username+"&password="+user.password;
OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(out);
dataOut.writeBytes(param.trim());
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String line;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line);
}
reader.close();
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

in `StringBuilder` you will get the output which is returned by the server.

it will submit your parameters to php page..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, those no longer work in API 22 as they are deprecated.

Comment: ok...i edited the answer..check with that..its working for me in my Java Desktop application..

Comment: I've implemented your method, and it wants to connect to the server, but it's getting a 408 code.

Comment: response code 408 is `RequestTimeOut`..it means your `URL` is not onilne or unable to visit that `URL`..check that your `WebService` is up and running..

Comment: working fine in my code....got the output from site as `"Account does not exist."`..

Comment: In the manifest, I have the following:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78551/discussion-between-alex-and-nirranjan-raut).

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
  HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

instead of

> conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

check That 
[HttpsURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html)

Comment: I've changed it to your suggestion, as well as removing the 'catch' as suggested above; however, it still isn't connecting and instead crashes the app. I've removed the: BufferRead section, to focus on simply posting to PHP and then worry about receiving the response.

Comment: i recommend u try to post data with poster plugin with your browser and check result

Comment: why is true ? //conn.setDoInput(true); //conn.setDoOutput(true);

Comment: I read somewhere that it was necessary to send data; if it's not needed, I can remove it. What's your thinking?

Comment: ok , first try to add time to request  conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);

Comment: second , after //out.write(param); add writer.flush();
            writer.close();

Answer (score 0):

Do like that.

```
new Login().execute(name, profilePic);//calling

public class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{
  String response="";
    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        postData(params[0],params[1]);

        return null;
    }




    public void postData(String name,String profilePic) {

        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("your_url");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Constants.AppId,Constants.Value_AppId ));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Constants.Tag_profile_name, name));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Constants.Tag_profile_pic, profilePic));


            httppost.setEntity((HttpEntity) new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse res = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             InputStream content = res.getEntity().getContent();

              BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
              String s = "";
              while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                response += s;
              }
              System.out.println("response from server"+response);


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you...!